# Need MAX value from (ex 1-100 in F:F) BUT I may need to withdraw some cells from the list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Need MAX value from (ex 1-100 in `F:F`). BUT I may need to withdraw some cells from the list.

For example, I have `F:F`. Each cell will contain a value from 1-100, but I may not need certain cells, but not the same ones every time.

Is there a formula to look for a list of (non functional), maybe for example:

```
=MAX(F:F)-(F4,F8,F163,F354,F574)
```

I know this does not work but I will be adding and removing cells from this list from time to time, since the list is very extensive, for example:

```
=MAX(F1:F5,F7:F16,F18:F41,F43:F66,F68:F91,F93:F197,F199:F219,F221:F291,F293:F312,F314:F900)
```

I know this works but omg. Would be a horrible thing to must change every time. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Array Formula formula:

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(MATCH("F" & ROW($F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,$F:$F))) & "|",$H$1:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH("ZZZ",$H:$H))&"|",0)),$F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,$F:$F))))
```

Notes:

1. Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.
2. The Cells to be ignored must be put one cell address at a time in a column.  Mine is in column H.

Description:

1. Being and array formula we want to limit the references to the data set.  The `$F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,$F:$F))` will do that.  It will create a range that includes F1 to the last cell in Column F that has a number.  The H column Reference finds every cell from H1 to the last cell with a string.
2. The If Function will then return an array of numbers and `FALSE`.  The False will be where the row number is equal to the cell reference.
3. The `"|"` is added to insure that we do not get false negatives.  Without it a reference in Column H of `F2` would exclude all cell references that start with `F2` including `F20`,`F21`...
4. The MAX() will ignore the `FALSE`s returned in the array and find the largest number left in the array returned by the IF statement.

[image]

---

You can also use this similar formula that does not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter, but is entered normally.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,$F:$F))/(ISERROR(MATCH("F" & ROW($F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(1E+99,$F:$F))) & "|",$H$1:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH("ZZZ",$H:$H))&"|",0))),1)
```

It is still considered an array formula so we need to limit the data references.

Comment: @NoEbb please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.